# Opentok [ v2.13 ] - Unable to publish on the session

Tags: opentok, tokbox, audio-source

I am using opentok library to perform video call. When I try to publish a publisher over a session with audioSource and videoSource both property set to null then I am not able to publish a publisher over a stream.

Getting below error.

Unable to publish, session timeout

1. [image: Error Reference]

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

The reason that you're unable to publish successfully is because you're setting both the `videoSource` and the `audioSource` properties to null. This means that neither the video nor the audio tracks will be initialized.

For more information on initializing the publisher, please check out the docs for [`initPublisher`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#initPublisher).